# Linspace using matrix input matlab

Tags: matlab

My question seems wierd, because I know that we can't use a matrix as input in `linspace(x1,x2,n)` function. But my question is more something like : I have a vector `A=linspace(0,Amax,N)`, and I want to build a serie of vector B_k or big matrix `B_k=linspace(0,A(k),N)` but without making a `for` loop that slows down my whole calculation.

```
% already defined A
rGC=linspace(0,75e-7,N);
for k=1:N
    r=rGC(k);
    v=linspace(0,A*r,N);
    y=f(r,v);
    INT=trapz(v,y);
    %  The same for 8 more integrals
end
```

Comment: A for loop will not slow your calculation.

Comment: Can you include code which does what you want using a for loop

Comment: It is to calculate numerically a double integral.

Comment: @AnderBiguri assuming the OP is using Matlab 2015b or later, otherwise it will be slower

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki It *may* be slower, if there exists a vectorized solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something using interp1, to interpolate something like:

```
[0    0    0    ... 0 ]
[A(1) A(2) A(3) ... A(N)]
```

with N rows .... For instance:

```
N = 5;
Amax = 15;
A = linspace(0, Amax, N);

x = [0 1];
y = zeros(2, N);
y(2, :) = A;

B = interp1(x, y, linspace(0, 1, N))
```

Which will give:

```
B =

     0         0         0         0         0
     0    0.9375    1.8750    2.8125    3.7500
     0    1.8750    3.7500    5.6250    7.5000
     0    2.8125    5.6250    8.4375   11.2500
     0    3.7500    7.5000   11.2500   15.0000
```

Not sure it will be any faster than a `for` loop or that even get the point here :)