# Creating multidimensional sequences in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I guess this question is pretty standard, but being new to MATLAB, I'm just not able to get the syntax right.

What I want to do is the following: given two vectors i and j, create a Matrix whose first row is i(1):j(1), the second row is i(2):j(2) and so on.
Obviously i:j or similar expressions don't work...

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I am looking for a solution without loops

Comment: Show the  values of `i` and `j`, a simple example. Read what a [mcve] is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linspace using matrix input matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783512/linspace-using-matrix-input-matlab),  [Linspace applied on array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114695/linspace-applied-on-array/49117114)

Comment: I don't want a solution for any specific i and j but a general way to do this, i.e. it should work for any vectors i and j as long as their components have the same difference (to make the matrix dimension agree)

Comment: @ Wolfie, yeah I think I can work with that, thank you!